# Background image with linear gradients in rails 5

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have simple CSS code for background image with linear gradients.

```
.main-bg-back-1{
    background:linear-gradient(180deg,#22263f,rgba(33,41,94,.96)),url(../img/app/download-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size:auto,cover;
    background-position:0 0,50% 50%
}
```

How can I write this in rails 5? I know `background-image: image-url("app/download-bg.jpg");` use for simple background in rails. But how I use the image with gradients?

Comment: i don't know rail but i think CSS should be the same ? a gradient is an image so simly write `background-image:linear-gradient(),url();`

Answer (score 1):

I have used something like this, try to the following

```
.main-bg-back-1{
    background-image: asset-url('download-bg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-position:0 0,50% 50%
}
.main-bg-back-1:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,#22263f,rgba(33,41,94,.96));
    mix-blend-mode: color;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

make sure the image in `app/assets/images` and use [`asset-url`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass)

> background-size: auto, cover;

you can use `auto` or `cover`, not both, and `mix-blend-mode: color;` is optional you can see removing and adding this.

I have tested out with your gradient value on my Rails application see this

[image]

**Update**

From the comment, it's also working

```
background-image:linear-gradient(),url();
```

Comment: yes its good way..but its also working with this strategy like ..background:linear-gradient(180deg,#22263f,rgba(33,41,94,.96)),url(app/download-bg.jpg) no-repeat;

Comment: its working in rails..i only skip the ../img and its working fine